# Can we get Column Name from specific Table in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Can we get Column Name from specific Table in Google BigQuery??

Let me know query for this activity.

I tried this but cant got result...

```
  SELECT column_name FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare
  OR
  SELECT schema FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare
```

Comment: So you want to do something like SELECT column_name FROM all_tables where table = 'shakespeare' and schema = 'publicdata:samples'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got result using Java:

```
Tables tableRequest = bigquery.tables();
Table table = tableRequest.get(projectName,datasetName,tableName).execute();
List<TableFieldSchema> fields = table.getSchema().getFields();
```

Answer (score 3):

1.You can use commandline tool (https://developers.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#gettable): 
bq show :.

```
$ bq show publicdata:samples.shakespeare
tableId      Last modified                  Schema
------------- ----------------- ------------------------------------
shakespeare   01 Sep 13:46:28   |- word: string (required)
                              |- word_count: integer (required)
                              |- corpus: string (required)
                              |- corpus_date: integer (required)
```

2.BigQuery Browser Tool : https://developers.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-browser-tool#examineschema

3.Or use BigQuery API: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get

Comment: i am using javascript so there is any method like this

var request = gapi.client.bigquery.schema.fields({
              'projectId': 'publicdata',
              'datasetId': 'samples',
              'tableId': 'shakespeare'
          });         
          request.execute(function(response) {
           console.log(response);
          });

if you any solution then lat me know?? Thanks

Comment: Option 3.BigQuery API: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get . This is REST API so, you can use in clean javascript or jQuery.

Comment: I think you have to use gapi.client.request https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientrequest

Answer (score 1):

Use [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#columns_view) to get column names with SQL:

```sql
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` 
WHERE table_name = 'shakespeare'
```

It gives you:

```
+-------------+-----------+
| column_name | data_type |
+-------------+-----------+
| word        | STRING    |
| word_count  | INT64     |
| corpus      | STRING    |
| corpus_date | INT64     |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to do a tables.list or tables.get and not a jobs.query.

This is how it works in google apps script:

```
var results = BigQuery.Tables.list(projectId, datasetId, optionalArgs);
```

Or by the API:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/datasets/datasetId/tables
```

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/list

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/datasets/datasetId/tables/tableId
```

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get

Otherwise, you can query like this SELECT * FROM [] limit 0 and write some procedure that looks at the column names.

Comment: My though was to select limit 1 and just use the column names too, but the error I get is "With this query, you will be billed for all the data in the table (even if your query contains a LIMIT clause)."

Answer (score 0):

A sample using python in Jupyter:

```
SERVICE_ACCOUNT = 'sa_bq.json'

!pip install google-cloud
!pip install google-api-python-client
!pip install oauth2client    

from google.cloud import bigquery

client_bq = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(SERVICE_ACCOUNT)
table = client_bq.get_table('bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare')
print(list(c.name for c in table.schema))
```

Comment: An update since latest library version, to use the table : 

`>> tr = bigquery.table.TableReference.from_string('bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare')
>> table = client_bq.get_table(tr)`

Answer (score 0):

Without any queries, on the Classic UI, you can proceed as follow:

- click on the blue down arrow on the left panel
- **Switch to project**, then **Display project...**
- on Project ID, write the name of the project (in your case you have `publicdata:samples.shakespeare`, your project is `publicdata`)
- now, this project appears on the left panel
- select the dataset (in your case it is Sample)
- select the table (in your case it is shakespeare)
- finally, in the middle of the screen you should see three tabs: Schema, Details, Preview.